# Error connect postgreSQL from Java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql

I am trying to connect to postgreSQL from Java eclipse

Here is the snapshot of the database structure. [image: Data base Structure]

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres", "postgres",
                    "admin");
```

when i am trying to connect to postgres database it works absolutely fine. but that is the default database which i don't want to connect.

```
 connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres", "han2012205",
                        "admin");
```

when i tried to access the han2012205 it is throwing this error.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "han201205"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:398)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:173)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:136)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:31)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at connectToDB.dbConnection.connectdatabase(dbConnection.java:26)
    at AdapterTest.main(AdapterTest.java:22)
```

Can some please help me with my problem

Hoping to hear back from some one soon!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've misunderstood the call you're making. You're using [`DriverManager.getConnection(String, String, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) - where the second parameter is the user, and the third parameter is the password. That's *not* the way to specify the database you want to connect to.

I suspect you want:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/han201205", "postgres",
                "admin");
```

Note how the database name is the last part of the JDBC connection URL, *not* the second parameter. (You may need to just the username and password, of course...)

See the [Postgres JDBC documentation](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/connect.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Also, the database is called "han201205", your code was looking for "han2012205" with an extra "2"

Comment: the extra 2 i added here by mistake. i am sure that is not the problem. Thanks!